# Task schedular does not giving output of Powershell script

Tags: sql-server, powershell, taskscheduler

On Windows 8, I want to schedule a SQL Server backup using two files:

powershell.ps1

```
sqlcmd -S GT044 -E -i backup.sql
```

and filename.sql

```
BACKUP DATABASE [DB_NAME] TO DISK ='D:\backup.bak'
```

When I manually run `powershell.ps1` in PowerShell, it works and backs up the database. But when I schedule the `powershell.ps1`, it does not backup the database.

Comment: What's the account the task is being run on?

Comment: If you have nothing but that one line in there `sqlcmd -S GT044 -E -i backup.sql`, there is no need to make a script at all, not even BAT. You can schedule `sqlcmd.exe` with the necessary parameters directly.

Comment: Tomalak is right but if you still want help getting task scheduler working (perhaps for other scripts in the future) show us the task scheduler configuration you are using, particularly the actions tab, along with the last run result.

Comment: argument pased are -NoProfile -NoLogo -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File D:\backup.ps1; quit

Comment: @Tomalak thanks for your comment can you please tell me the way how can i schdule this with sqlcmd.exe only.

Comment: No, I won't. You will need to think about it yourself.